# Green function for Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, galaxies, software, greens-functions

In the context of a project, I had to solve numerically Poisson equation with cylindrical coordinates. I put here results for z = 0 on a 3D mesh 256x256x256.

When I define Green function, have I to add a factor space_x, space_y and space_z (size of cell on the grid) respectively for `dx, dy, dz` ? I mean like this below :

```
 dx = sqrt(pow((double) (i-Ng/2),2.0))*space_x;
 dy = sqrt(pow((double) (j-Ng/2),2.0))*space_y;
 dz = sqrt(pow((double) (k-Ng/2),2.0))*space_z;
```

If I don't add these factors, i.e :

```
 dx = sqrt(pow((double) (i-Ng/2),2.0));
 dy = sqrt(pow((double) (j-Ng/2),2.0));
 dz = sqrt(pow((double) (k-Ng/2),2.0));
```

I don't know if I have to include these `space_x, space_y and space_z` in Green function.

Any help is welcome,

Comment: I'm voting this question as off topic because it is about debugging code and not physics.

Comment: Hi user1773603. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gravitational potential at the point $ \vec{x_0} $ of a collection of $ n $ point objects of mass $ M_i $ each located at a point $ \vec{x_i} $ is:

\begin{align}
\Phi = \Sigma_{i=1}^{n} \frac{-GM_i}{|\vec{x_i}-\vec{x_0}|}
\end{align}

I'm not entirely use what you are doing with the Green's function array (is this a built in function?), but for this problem it is unnecessary as you can simply sum up the contribution from each mass. Also, are your stars spaced only along x? If not, it looks like you might have a looping error:

```
for (i=0; i< numStars; i++)
{
   dx = sqrt(pow((double) (i-Ng/2),2.0))*space_x;
   dy = sqrt(pow((double) (j-Ng/2),2.0))*space_y;
   dz = sqrt(pow((double) (k-Ng/2),2.0))*space_z;

   green_grid[i][j][k] = -1.0/(4.0*M_PI*sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz));
}
```

Since i is referring both to the star entry and its x position?